# How to break animation and run it again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have a page with some anchors and links which lead on this anchors. I can click on the link and the anchor's background-color will become some color. With help of animation I make this backgound-color dissapear in 10 sec - first I make background-color white than I remove class and styles from element to reuse it.

But when I click on the link and go to the anchor which animation haven't finished, the color is not the same as the color on start of animation, it continue becoming more transpanent.

I want to click the same link again (for the anchor which hasn't finished dissapearing) and animation on this anchor have to stop and run again with full color of background. How can I do it?

The example of code:

```
$("a").each(function () {
      $(this).click(function () {
            const anchorName = this.href.slice(this.href.indexOf('#'));
                goToAnchor(decodeURIComponent(anchorName));
            });
    });

const goToAnchor = (anchorId) => {
 const anchor = document.getElementById(anchorId.replace('#', ''));
 const nextElem = $(anchor).parent().text() !== '' ? $(anchor).parent() : $(anchor).parent().next();
$(nextElem).addClass('focus-on-anchor');
$(nextElem).clearQueue();
(function (elem) {
    $(elem).animate({
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,255,255)'
    }, 10000, function () {
        $(this).removeAttr('class style');
    });
}(nextElem));
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fiorsaoirse/j247atLc/13/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do is to add checking on having 'style' in element before running the animation:

```
$("a").each(function () {
      $(this).click(function () {
            const anchorName = this.href.slice(this.href.indexOf('#'));
                goToAnchor(decodeURIComponent(anchorName));
            });
    });

const goToAnchor = (anchorId) => {
 const anchor = document.getElementById(anchorId.replace('#', ''));
 const nextElem = $(anchor).parent().text() !== '' ? $(anchor).parent() : $(anchor).parent().next();
    $(nextElem).addClass('focus-on-anchor');
    $(nextElem).stop().clearQueue();
    if ($(nextElem).is('[style]')) {
    // In case when animation hasn't stopped yet
        $(nextElem).removeAttr('style');
  }
 makeElemDisappear($(nextElem));
}

const makeElemDisappear = (elem) => {
$(elem).animate({
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,255,255)'
    }, 10000, function () {
        $(this).removeAttr('class style');
    });
}
```